# How to fix converting data models in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

[image]I'm getting the following error when trying to load data into a blazor component.

```
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Gars.DataModels.Picks>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<GarsApp.Pages.Picks>'
```

Below is the code that is causing the problem.  There is no such thing as GarsApp.Pages.Picks.   All my data is in DataModels library.

```
@code {
private List<GameData> _gameData = new List<GameData>();
private int _currentWeek;
private List<Picks> _currentPicks = new List<Picks>();



protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var authSate = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authSate.User;


    _gameData = await gameRepo.GetCurrentGames();
    _currentWeek = await gameRepo.GetCurrentWeek();

    // _currentPicks = _db.Picks.Where(x => x.UserId == user.Identity.Name && x.Week == _currentWeek).ToList<Picks>();

    _currentPicks = await pickRepo.LoadPicks(user.Identity.Name, _currentWeek);


}
```

Picks is ONLY declared in one place.  How does it think the Model is GarsApp.Pages.Picks?   Any ideas ?  The error occurs at the bottom where I try to assign _currentPicks variable.

Adding using and inject statements.

```
@using Gars.DataModels;
@using GarsApp.Repsositories;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
 
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

@inject GameDataRepo gameRepo
@inject PickRepo pickRepo
@inject ApplicationDbContext _db
```

Comment: _"There is no such thing as GarsApp.Pages.Picks"_ ...there must be. The software isn't lying you to. If you're using visual studio, you can hover over the `Picks` type in the code and it'll tell you the namespace. You can right-click on it and go to the class, too.

Comment: Also do you have any `using` statements at the top of your page, or in your Imports.razor which might reference the relevant namespace?

Comment: Added image that it can not navigate to the class.

Comment: Ok. That sometimes happens with classes loaded from another assembly, where the source code is not available to VS. If you just hover over it, does it tell you the namespace the class belongs to? It **must** be a different type than the type which the `LoadPicks` method returns, otherwise you wouldn't have the error.

Comment: Yes, it says GarsApp.Pages.Picks.     GarsApp.Pages is where the Picks razor page is located.  No classes in this namespace.

Comment: ok well, somewhere in your application, this class exists and is defined as belonging to the GapsApp.Pages namespace. Maybe in another assembly even, but it's definitely there. And it doesn't match the type that `LoadPicks` returns. So when you declare `_currentPicks` you need to specify the exact type you want, so there's no confusion. e.g. `List<Gars.DataModels.Picks> _currentPicks = new List<Gars.DataModels.Picks>();`

Comment: I'll search some more to figure out if that class would exist somewhere else.  It's a small app so.   Thanks for hints.  If I find my problem I'll update the post.

Comment: @ADyson  I put full path into the declaration and it's working now.   Somehow somewhere there is a class out there I don't want.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad that works. I added it as a proper answer below, now we're sure that solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your application, a class exists called `Picks` and is defined as belonging to the `GapsApp.Pages` namespace. Maybe it's in another assembly even, but it's definitely there. And it doesn't match the type that the `LoadPicks` method returns, hence the error.

Therefore when you declare `_currentPicks` you need to specify the exact type you want, so there's no confusion.

e.g.

```
List<Gars.DataModels.Picks> _currentPicks = new List<Gars.DataModels.Picks>();
```